# Archivos incompletos al enviar por sockets

Tags: python, socket

Tengo el codigo de un servidor y un cliente, sin embargo cuando quiero enviar un archivo llega incompleto:

en este caso el servidor espera que el cliente mande la palabra `archivo` para poder mandar la imagen

pero llega incompleta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si quiero que llege completa necesito mandar muchos mensajes al servidor hasta que llegue completa

**Funcion esperada:**
La intencion con esto es que el usuario pueda pedir el archivo en cualquier momento de la conversasion por poner un ejemplo y que despues pueda mandar mensajes de nuevo

**Espero puedan ayudarme**

**servidor.py**

```
import socket

ip = "0.0.0.0"
puerto = 8083
data = (ip,puerto)
conexionesMaximas = 10

socketSer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketSer.bind(data)
socketSer.listen(conexionesMaximas)

cliente,direccion = socketSer.accept()

f = open("Captura.PNG","rb")
content = f.read(1024)

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(datos)
    if datos == "exit":
        cliente.sendall("exit".encode())
        break

    elif datos == "archivo":
        while content:
            cliente.send(content)
            content = f.read(1024)
        socketSer.close()
        f.close()
    cliente.sendall("recibido".encode())
socketSer.close()
```

**cliente.py**

```
import socket

ipser = "192.168.8.3"
puerto = 8083

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((ipser,puerto))

f = open("dos.PNG","wb")
while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode())
    input_data  = cliente.recv(4024)
    try:
        #input_data.decode()
        print(input_data)
        if input_data.decode()=="exit":
            break
    except:
        if len(input_data)==0:
            print("archivo")
            break
        f.write(input_data)
        #cliente.close()
        #f.close()
cliente.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que en TCP no existe el concepto de "mensaje" como una unidad. Lo que envías por TCP son bytes individuales, y no agrupados en "mensajes".

Quiero decir con esto que uno de los extremos puede enviar un mensaje así:

```
s.sendall(b"Esto es una prueba")
```

y el otro extremo estar esperando por un mensaje así:

```
msg = s.recv(1024)
```

y **no debes suponer** que lo que recibirás en `msg` vaya a ser `b"Esto es una prueba"`. Podrías recibir simplemente `b"Esto"`, por ejemplo. La API TCP no crea mensajes "indivisibles" cuando haces un `send()`, ni los recibe de forma atómica. Al hacer el `send()` simplemente el operativo irá creando paquetes TCP/IP que contendrán partes de tu mensaje y enviándolos por la red. El otro extremo los recibirá (quizás en otro orden), los reagrupará en el orden correcto y le irá dando los bytes recibidos a quien se los pida con `recv()`. Pero es posible que no hayan llegado aún todos y que el resultado sea "lo que ha llegado de momento".

Quien recibe *no sabe* cuántos bytes envió el otro. Por tanto si tras hacer `s.recv()` has recibido `b"Hola"` no tienes forma de saber si ese era el mensaje completo, o si ese era sólo el comienzo y faltan más por leer. Si de alguna forma supieras de antemano que el cliente te ha enviado 18 bytes, entonces al ver que `recv()` te ha retornado sólo 4 *sí sabrías* que aún faltan 14 más, por lo que podrías hacer otro `recv()` para recibir más, e ir concatenando la respuesta.

TCP no te resuelve por sí solo el problema. Tienes que utilizar algún algoritmo para *delimitar mensajes* (*framing*) en la capa de aplicación.

Por ejemplo, uno de los extremos podría enviar siempre, delante de cada mensaje, cuál es la longitud en bytes del mensaje. Esa longitud podría ser una cadena ASCII como "6738", que indicaría que el mensaje tiene 6738 bytes. Entonces a continuación ya podría iterar en `recv()` hasta haber recibido esa cantidad de bytes.

Naturalmente tenemos ahora otro problema, y es cómo saber dónde termina la cadena inicial que indica la longitud y donde empieza el mensaje. Esto puedes resolverlo haciendo que la cadena sea siempre de la misma longitud, por ejemplo 10 cifras, con relleno de ceros por la izquierda. O que la cadena vaya terminada con un byte especial, como por ejemplo `\n`. Una vez decidas cómo hacerlo, deberás implementar tu protocolo de forma apropiada para que detecte esa cadena inicial, la convierta a entero, y  la use para recibir ese número de bytes detrás.